# How to support Right-to-Left direction language in jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, right-to-left

how to support Right-to-Left direction language in jQueryUI?

I'm about to start a jQueryUI based web app and before I start coding I wanted to know How is it possible to set direction of object in jQueryUI RightToLeft?

The default direction of the jQueryUI object is from left to right. How do I change it direction right to left ?